# SQL para recuperar los nombres de datos de una tabla que sólo tiene IDs de otras tablas

Tags: sql, datatables

Tengo 4 tablas (esto después será exponencial):

```
T1 LOCALES (
id (pk), nombre, dirección, id_encargado (fk), cant_empleados (campo calculado)
)
T2 ENCARGADOS (
id (pk), nombre, apellido, telefono, email, id_horario (fk)
)
T3 HORARIOS (
id_horario (pk), id_encargado (fk), id_franjahoraria (fk)
)
T4 FRANJAHORARIA(
id_franjahoraria (pk), tipo_franja, hor_aper, hor_cierre
)
```

Mi problema esta en que no logro una Query funcional, por más que uso los JOIN e intento anidar SELECTS, no logro obtener un resultado de la tabla HORARIOS, expresado de la siguiente manera:

```
| Nombre (encargado) | Apellido (encargado) | Tipo Franja (las correspondientes por ID de encargado) |
```

Básicamente, no logro mostrar el descriptivo real del campo para cada una de las FK de la tabla HORARIOS.

Estaría muy agradecido si me pueden ayudar =)

Comment: Hola! En qué motor de bd?

Comment: Hola!, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. SQLServer

Answer (score 0):

Esto se ve relativamente simple:

```
SELECT
    e.nombre,
    e.apellido,
    fh.tipo_franja
FROM dbo.Horarios h
JOIN dbo.Encargados e
    ON e.id = h.id_encargado
JOIN dbo.FranjaHoraria fh
    ON fh.id = h.id_franjahoraria
;
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta!. Esta sentencia es como las que venía realizando, y me devuelve el valor de las ID FK de la tabla horarios, y no como resultado "el nombre real del encargado", su "apellido" y el "tipo franja horaria", me devuelve los ID en valor numérico. Yo necesito que me devuelva, Ej: 'Carlos', 'Gonzalez', 'Matutina'.

Comment: pues la verdad es que no veo cómo este código te podría devolver los IDs, si está usando las con los nombres, seguro probaste la consulta que escribí?